# Jenkins Slave not responding to create work space

Tags: jenkins, ssh

My Jenkins is not able to create work space due to a permission issue. I don't how to resolve this issue.

```
[12/30/19 17:21:18] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[12/30/19 17:21:18] [SSH] java -version returned 11.0.5.
[12/30/19 17:21:18] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[12/30/19 17:21:18] [SSH] Remote file system root /home/jenkins/agent/workspace does not exist. Will try to create it...
java.io.IOException: Could not copy remoting.jar into '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace' on agent
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copyAgentJar(SSHLauncher.java:702)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$300(SSHLauncher.java:113)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:445)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:412)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdir /home/jenkins/agent
    at com.trilead.ssh2.jenkins.SFTPClient.mkdirs(SFTPClient.java:91)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.jenkins.SFTPClient.mkdirs(SFTPClient.java:86)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copyAgentJar(SSHLauncher.java:659)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.trilead.ssh2.SFTPException: Permission denied (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SFTPv3Client.expectStatusOKMessage(SFTPv3Client.java:555)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SFTPv3Client.mkdir(SFTPv3Client.java:955)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.jenkins.SFTPClient.mkdirs(SFTPClient.java:89)
    [12/30/19 17:21:18] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[12/30/19 17:21:18] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Comment: Which user is Jenkins running as?

Comment: Jenkins is running with my name,  but resolved this issue updating chmod in Jenkins build workspace.

Comment: Please find the jenkins workspace and do the below changes.  chmod 755 jenkins/build-workspace